# Shortest way to to write split function and assign variables?

Tags: python, function, variables, join, split

**I'm looking for a shorter but still clean and flexible way to write what I have below.**

Variable to work with (length varying)

```
drpfile_exportname = '1911_CocaCola_XMasNow_TVC30sec_03_Roughcut_Tv10_PV01_Ov01_200319_prev_for_approval_H264'
```

Long way of doing it but clean

```
# Split string by "_"
drpfile_exportname_list = drpfile_exportname.split("_")
# Set variables
ul_date = drpfile_exportname_list[0]
up_client = drpfile_exportname_list[1]
up_cprojname = drpfile_exportname_list[2]
# Join variables to create desired name
upload_projname = "_".join((ul_date, up_client, up_cprojname))
```

Alternative oneliner not so flexible as no variables are assigned and in my opinion not a beautiful way to solve it

```
upload_projname = ("_".join(drpfile_exportname.split('_')[0:3]))
```

Thought something like this would work but always had problems with it

```
ul_date, up_client, up_cprojname = drpfile_exportname.split('_', 2)
```

Print:

```
print("\nProject name:    {}".format(upload_projname))
```

Result that should be stored in a variable:

Project name:    `1911_CocaCola_XMasNow`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can slice the result of split.

```
ul_date, up_client, up_cprojname = drpfile_exportname.split('_')[:3]
```

Or you can assign a dummy variable to the part you want to ignore

```
ul_date, up_client, up_cprojname, *_ = drpfile_exportname.split('_')
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. Very much appreciated. I used the sliced result of split already but tried to find a oneliner. But I think there is no way to also assign the upload_projname variable in the same line, right? Thanks for the "dummy variable" way, I didn't know that one!

Comment: You can't assign the individual variables and also `upload_projname` in a one-liner.